# Opening a db file with ANSYS APDL failed

Tags: ansys, ansys-apdl

When I open a .db file using ANSYS APDL "Read Input from..." I get the following error:
DURING FILE BASE INPUT (/INPUT OR MACRO) 5 WARNINGS OCCURRED. SHOULD INPUT PROCESSING BE SUSPENDED?

[image: Error popup message]
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In Mechanical APDL databases, files with extension of db, are resumed and not input.  The /input command is meant to read files of APDL commands.  So try the RESUME command instead if the file really is a db file.

Mike